# WCF response customization

Tags: wcf

I have developed a WCF service whose response is like this -

```
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <getNameResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.com/">
            <name>4</name>
        </getNameResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

But I need response in the following format-

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<a:getNameResponse xmlns:a="http://tempuri.com/">
<name>4</name>
</a:getNameResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to configure WCF service to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this - I've posted about customizing prefixes for WCF services at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx. However, notice that the two responses you have are not equivalent - in the first one, the `<name>` element is on the namespace "http://tempuri.org/", while on the second one, it's on the empty ("") namespace. If that's really what you need, you may want to consider using a message contract to change the namespace of the body elements.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Isn't there any standard WCF configuration through which we can achieve this??

Comment: No, since it *shouldn't* matter (and it doesn't in most of the cases), there's no "standard" knob in WCF to tweak it.